# What are the prerequisites for learning abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning, learning, online-resources

Well, I want to learn abstract algebra. So, I get across this http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra. But I'm not sure whether I've understanding of prerequisites so wanted to know this.

PS- I know the whole high school syllabus and fractions afterwards from various resources.

Comment: then tell us what do you know!

Comment: I'd say for most students the best thing is to have done a course in Linear Algebra.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/258199/118539

Answer (score 0):

If only there were documents that laid out the plan for a course, including ideas for study, prerequisite materials, and suggested reading.

Oh wait. Those exist!

A document like that is called a *syllabus*, and if you [search for those keywords](https://www.google.com/#q=%22abstract+algebra%22+syllabus) you get thousands of hits, some of which would probably be helpful. The first hit for me was authored by Michael Hutchings, and seems to be very relevant to you.

Leverage the already huge amount of information available before asking others to compile the work for you, please!