# Studying Algebraic structure [serge Lang]

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I was searching about a reference of Algebraic Structures I found Serge Lang's book with that title and to make sure it's suitable for understanding the notion of Algebraic structure I searched the the forum here .. the most related post here about serge Lang's book was that post : [A Book for abstract Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239734/a-book-for-abstract-algebra)
The correct answer by "Javier Álvarez" tells him among his first lines it depends on your aim .... now If My aim is to study the notion of Algebraic structure as one of the three mother structures (algebraic,topological,order) 
keeping in mind is that my back ground in propositional and predicate logic is good and I am going to read ZFC well ... Does This book suitable for my aim ... am asking that question because too many answers suggested books with title abstract algebra ..

thanks

Comment: I haven't seen the book you're talking about, but my guess is that it might be an early edition of Lang's *Undergraduate Algebra*. If that's the case, then yes, it will provide a good introduction to algebraic structures. However, this is also the case of many books with names such as "algebra," "modern algebra" and "abstract algebra." I don't imagine that a book with that exact title would be more about algebraic structures than other books on abstract algebra.

Comment: @user49640 Thanks for your Answer ... I was searching Wikipedia first and that's what made stick to that title when I asked the question .. What's your opinion about "van der waerden" book Algebra I,II ?

Comment: I know that those books are classics, and that many of the best mathematicians learned from those books. But I've never used them myself. As I understand things, you are coming to mathematical logic from a non-mathematical field, and you would like to get some background in mathematics for logic (for example, model thoery). Is that correct?

Comment: yes, From a Computer Engineering field I studied propositional logic and predicate logic ... I am interested in Signal processing and Cryptography

Comment: There are abstract algebra books at different levels of difficulty. An easy introductory book would be *Abstract Algebra* by Herstein. If your goal were to study mathematics in the same way a math major would, I would recommend *Algebra* by Artin. Lang's *Undergraduate Algebra* is intermediate between those two in terms of completeness and difficulty.

Comment: @user49640 Thanks for your help